# Can't get a scrollable div in a div table / cell bootstrap structure

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I use Bootstrap 4 and I can't make a scrollable div inside a structure where 2 divs are side by side, the right div has a fixed width and the second div to the right take all the left space responsively.

The working code:

```
<div class="d-table mt-3" style="width:100%;">
   <div class="d-table-cell" style="width:200px">
       Menu Left
   </div>
   <div class="d-table-cell bg-success">
      Hello world
   </div>
</div>
```

The scrollable div working code:

```
  <div class="mx-auto bg-warning overflow-auto" style="width:100%;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
  </div>
```

But If I place the scrollable div inside the Hello world d-table-cell div, it just does not work. `overflow-x: auto` has no effect.

I have done a jsfiddle (just remove display:none !important; from the second d-table div):
https://jsfiddle.net/LondonUK371/zdcjfmv6/8/

How to do that, a scrollable div where "Hello world" is? It can be either with or without Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the style `table-layout: fixed` to the div with the `.d-table` class. This will prevent the table cell effecting the overall width of the table.

https://jsfiddle.net/WizardCoder/6gmryqca/6/

> **Table Layout Fixed**
> Sets a fixed table layout algorithm. The table and column widths are
> set by the widths of table and col or by the width of the first row of
> cells. Cells in other rows do not affect column widths. If no widths
> are present on the first row, the column widths are divided equally
> across the table, regardless of content inside the cells

**CSS**

```
.cell {
  width:300px;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.table-layout-fixed {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mx-auto bg-warning overflow-auto" style="width:100%;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
    <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
</div>

<div class="d-table mt-3" style="width:100%;">
   <div class="d-table-cell" style="width:200px">
       Menu Left
   </div>
   <div class="d-table-cell bg-success">
      Hello world
   </div>
</div>

<div class="d-table mt-3 table-layout-fixed" style="width:100%;">
   <div class="d-table-cell" style="width:200px">
       Menu Left
   </div>
   <div class="d-table-cel bg-success">
      <div class="mx-auto bg-warning overflow-auto" style="width:100%;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
        <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
        <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
        <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
        <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
        <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
        <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
        <div class="cell d-inline-block"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the WizardCoder solution I have noticed by chance that we can put the `table-layout:fixed` inside the table cell div where we want the long div with a scrollbar:

```
     <div class="d-table" style="table-layout: fixed;width:100%;">  
        <div class="bg-warning overflow-auto" style="white-space: nowrap;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
...
        </div>
      </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LondonUK371/a6cm9xs5/

This can be useful if we can't figure out why the `table-layout:fixed` at the top d-table div is not enough.